# Why does a defaulted default constructor depend on whether it is declared inside or outside of class?

Tags: c++, default, default-constructor, defaulted-functions

In the following example, `struct A` does not have default constructor. So both `struct B` and `struct C` inherited from it cannot get compiler-generated default constructor:

```
struct A {
    A(int) {}
};

struct B : A {
    B() = default; //#1
};

struct C : A {
    C();
};

C::C() = default; //#2
```

#1. In `struct B`, defaulted default constructor is declared inside the class, and all compilers accept it, with only Clang showing a warning saying that `explicitly defaulted default constructor is implicitly deleted [-Wdefaulted-function-deleted]`

#2. But defaulted default constructor declared outside of `struct C` generates a compiler error. Demo:  https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3EGc4rTqE

Why does it matter where the constructor is defaulted: inside or outside the class?

Comment: Because that's how the syntax is defined in the standard

Comment: *Why does it matter where the constructor is defaulted: inside or outside the class?* -- Maybe the simple answer is "those are the current rules of C++"?  If you have a line or paragraph in the standard that allows your code to compile, but it doesn't compile for those compilers you tested for, you could state it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie cop-out answer. *Why are those the current rules of C++?*

Comment: @user253751 Follow-up.  Go ask the committee.  Or suggest it to them and see what happens.  No different than asking "why static initializers are not allowed in classes" back in the C++98 days.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Many questions about the C++ language design have reasonable answers. Like Alan's answer to this question.

Comment: @user253751 Then does this all become opinion-based?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie only in your mind and nobody else's. "Why can't I dereference an uninitialized pointer?" "Because the standard says so."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244111/discussion-between-paulmckenzie-and-user253751).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that if you actually try and instantiate `B` then you'll also get the error that `B::B()` is deleted: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jdKzv7zvd

The reason for the difference is probably that when you declare the `C` constructor, the users of `C` (assuming the definition is in another translation unit) have no way of knowing that the constructor is in fact deleted. At best this would lead to some confusing linker error, at worst it'd just crash at runtime. In the case of `B` all users of `B` will immediately be able to tell that the default constructor is deleted so it does no harm (even if it makes no sense as warned by clang) to declare it as defaulted.